# Set environment variables for a embedded python distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm using the "Embedded Distribution" for Windows new in Python 3.5.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) states, that it's:

> ... fully isolated from the user’s system, including environment variables, ...

Is there any way to set an environment variable, particular PYTHONPATH?

I'm running unittests with py.test and I'd like to use PYTHONPATH the make the module under test loadable from within the test directory.

Comment: set environment variable from within python?

Comment: Have you tried `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ...`?